# Does SharpGL Support Quad Buffer Stereo?

Tags: wpf, opengl, stereo-3d

I'm looking for a platform to display a pair of stereo bitmap images to a user wearing shutter glasses.  I'm exploring the possibility of implementing this in OpenGL via SharpGL.  My target is WPF but Winforms would not a deal breaker.  So... Can SharpGL do this?

If not, any suggestions on a platform?  I don't need 3D, per se, just a way to sync up left/right stereo images with a pair of shutter glasses.  I've been mucking about with NVidia 3D Vision via DirectX but the methodology seems to be clunky and proprietary, not to mention that we'd be limited to full-screen.  I'm liking what I'm seeing in OpenGL but the drawback there is that to do stereo we'd be limited to quad buffer enabled video cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching this for a couple weeks, I've come to the conclusion that SharpGL does not support quad buffering.  Even though the buffer names are enumerated, they don't appear to actually do anything.

OpenTK appears to work, but as of this writing does not have a native WPF control.

Answer (score 0):

look this for View trasform:

http://www.orthostereo.com/geometryopengl.html

Use two opengl viewport and direct data into two view when redraw.

Comment: please do not post only a link